# RSSI Statistics of Kontakt ibeacons set to Eddystone format

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, ibeacon-android, eddystone-url

I have Kontakt ibeacons whose profile i have changed to Eddystone format using configuration app from Kontakt.Now,i am using LOCATE application to calibrate the beacons and also to measure RSSI for different distances.Since few factors like RSSI,uptime,Advertising counts are higly unstable and keeps on fluctuating,i would like to know how would i get the statistics of every RSSI(fluctuating) value or how could i plot most of the RSSI samples against different distances,advertising intervals and transmission power?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the calibrate function of the Locate app to get a 30 second running average of the RSSI at various distances.  The instructions for this screen tell you to take the measurement at 1 meter, but for your purposes you can do it at different distances.

You would certainly want to do your plot vs. different transmitter power levels and distances, but you do not need to do so vs different advertising intervals -- that does not affect RSSI.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer.Could you please tell me is there a way to get the battery performance by setting different advertising intervals of Kontakt beacons or Can you please tell me how can i represent battery performance against advertising intervals graphically?

Comment: You would have to ask Kontakt for this info or measure it yourself.  In general, an advertising interval twice as fast will use twice as much battery.